Firestore security listing on sub collection
I have a collection of organizations /organizations and a collection of users /users. The organizations collection has a subgroup of groups /organizations/org1/groups.
Currently I have a security rule that means that users can only see the organization they are a member of by use of the organization_id field against the user document, however I don't seem to be able to restrict listing of the groups sub collection.
Here is what I've tried -
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /organization/{organizationId} {
        allow create:
            if request.auth != null;
        allow read, update:
            if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.auth.uid)).data.organization_id == organizationId;
        match /group/{groupId} {
            allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.auth.uid)).data.organization_id == organizationId;
        }
    }
    match /user/{user} {
        allow create, read:
            if request.auth != null;
        allow update: 
            if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.auth.uid)).data.is_global_admin == true
    }
  }
}

And the query to list the organizations for a group -
async getGroupsForOrg(org: string) {
    const groupsRef = collection(this.db, `organizations/${org}/groups`)
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(groupsRef)
    const groups = querySnapshot.docs.map((s) => {
      var g = s.data() as IGroup
      g.id = s.id
      return g
    })
    return groups
}

I just get access denied messages when I try to list groups in my organization. Retrieving a single group document seems to work ok.

Please edit your question to show the code that is not working against these rules.

Firebase security rules don't filter data, but rather only check to make sure your code only accesses data it is authorized for.
This means that you need to always make sure your code only tries to read data that it is authorized for.
In your case that would mean that you in a single query have to filter on the organization_id in the user document. And Firestore queries can only filter on data that is in the documents that it returns. So since you're trying to read from groups, you can only filter on data in the groups documents themselves. There is no way to join the data from the user document into the query.

So you'll either have to duplicate the relevant data from the user document into the group documents, or you'll have to model the data differently to allow the query. For example, you could store the groups the user has access to as a separate list for the user, so that you can perform the access check when you write that secondary list and don't have to perform it at read time.
This type of trade-off (making writes more complex to simplify reads) is very common when dealing with NoSQL databases. If you're new to this, you may want to check out NoSQL data modeling techniques and Get to know Cloud Firestore.
If you're more comfortable with SQL/relational databases, consider using either Firebase Data Connect - or one of the many SQL databases outside of Firebase.

Thanks Frank, appreciate the response. Completely my fault for not including the code in the question. Understand the concepts of NoSQL and I'm not doing any filtering in the query, I'm just using the user attribute to work out which organization to run the query against, if that makes sense.

You'll want to read the first link in my answer then, as security rules don't by themselves filter the data.
